# Force logged in users to provide more data when commenting

Tags: comments

I have added more data to my comment using hooks. I added a group of radio buttons so users can select and choose one of radio buttons. Everything works perfectly fine but the newly added radio buttons do not show up when you're already logged in.. they only show up and work when you are not logged in.  Logged in users only see the comment box.

How to show the newly added field alongside with the comment box to logged in user?

this is what I added to my functions.php

```
function add_comment_fields($fields) {

    if(is_user_logged_in()) {

        $fields['age'] = '<p class="comment-form-age"><label for="age">' . __( 'Age' ) . '</label>' .
        '<input id="age" name="age" type="text" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';
        return $fields;
    }
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','add_comment_fields');


function add_comment_meta_values($comment_id) {

    if(isset($_POST['age'])) {
        $age = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['age']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'age', $age, false);
    }

}
add_action ('comment_post', 'add_comment_meta_values', 1);
```

Comment: Try to explain the same in terms of code. You are free to [edit] the Question whenever needed.

Comment: this really depends on your theme and comment form template

Comment: I am working with twenty twelve theme

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to save all your additional data on as [user meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta), which would allow you to retrieve it when a comment is posted by a logged in user and store a copy of it along side the comment as you would for non-logged in users. Naturally this depends on the kind of data, and the extent to which it has to be unique for each comment.

An alternative approach might be to hook into the [`comment_form_top`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1560) action, which is called by `comment_template()` before printing the comment form. Assuming that you have added the additional fields using the `comment_form_default_fields` filter, you would then just do something like this:

```
function get_extra_fields() {
    return array('age' => '<p class="comment-form-age"><label for="age">' . __( 'Age' ) . '</label>' .
        '<input id="age" name="age" type="text" size="30"' . '' . ' /></p>');
}

function add_comment_fields($fields) {

    $fields = array_merge($fields, get_extra_fields());

    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','add_comment_fields');


function add_comment_meta_values($comment_id) {

    if(isset($_POST['age'])) {
        $age = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['age']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'age', $age, false);
    }

}
add_action ('comment_post', 'add_comment_meta_values', 1);


function add_comment_fields_logged_in() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in())
        return;

    $fields = get_extra_fields();

    foreach ( $fields as $name => $field ) {
        echo apply_filters( "comment_form_field_{$name}", $field ) . "\n";
    }
}
add_filter('comment_form_logged_in_after', 'add_comment_fields_logged_in');
```

Possibly you will also need to do some checking to verify that all required data has been submitted by the form etc., but that will likely apply for non-logged in users as well.

Comment: Simon, WordPress by default, shows only the comment box to logged in user, because it already has collected the user's name and email address.  I want to show this additional field when the user is logged in alongside with the comment box.  I updated my question, please see the code I am using. Thanks!

Comment: I might have had an error in my previous code example, but basically that should have worked (as long as I understand you question correctly, but I think I do). I've updated my answer and exchanged `comment_form_top` to `comment_form_logged_in_after`, and broken out the $fields setup to a separate function (`get_extra_fields`) which can be used both for logged in and non-logged in users. The supplied code adds the Age field above to comment box in both cases.

Comment: Simon, it worked like a charm!.. Thank you so much!